# Unir consulta en una base de datos Sql Server y una DBF en C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Estimada comunidad me pueden ayudar con lo siguiente tengo dos base de datos una en SQL SERVER realice la conexión con ADO.NET y la otra es una base de datos DBF la cual realice una clase para la conexión de la misma, deseo realizar una comparación de datos de una tabla a la otra ya que tienen la misma estructura y deseo ver que datos faltan tanto de la de SQL SERVER como la de DBF.

```
namespace log{
static class Program{
 private static ECEntities1 dc = new ECEntities1();
     public static void Main(){

//Consulta BDD SQL SERVER
var query =
                          from HInvoice in dc.HInvoice
                          where HInvoice.DOB == '2020-03-01'
                        select HInvoice.DOB
//Imprime datos
   foreach (var item in query)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(item);
                    }

//Consulta BDD BDF
 string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"db";
                    DataTable dt = DBF.ObtenerDatos(path, "GNDITEM.Dbf");

                   

                    
//Imprime datos
                    foreach (DataRow dtRow in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        // On all tables' columns
                        foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                        {
                            var field1 = dtRow[dc].ToString();
                            Console.WriteLine(field1);
                        }
                    }

}}}
```

Comment: Y ¿cuál es la dificultad o error que tienes?

Comment: Como uno la consulta de las dos tablas de las  base de datos DBF y la de SQL Server para realizar la comparación?

Comment: Pero tuviste algun problema comparando fila a fila? lo mejor seria que lo metas en una estructura que te permita ir comparando fila a fila...

Comment: @gbianchi eso es lo que quiero saber como lo meto en una estructura.

Comment: tu dt ya es una estructura que te permite comparar... si no, podrias generar clases y cargarlas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me responderé a mi mismo, yo soy nuevo así que la pregunta era como podría estar enfocado, pero ese no era el camino así que cambie el enfoque lo que realice fue lo siguiente:

Cree un proyecto nuevo en donde la tabla DBF la envié a mi base de datos Sql Server mediante un store procedure y desde ahí realizar la comparación

Crear la conexión a la base de datos Dbf.

```
 OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection();
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                OleDbCommand cmd;
                string PathArchivo = (@"\\ruta_archivo");
                string NombreArchivo = "GNDITEM.Dbf";

                
                    

cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + @PathArchivo + ";Extended Properties=dBASE IV;User ID=;Password=";
                    cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from " + NombreArchivo, cnn);
                    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    cnn.Close();
                    var dt = new DataTable();
                    da.Fill(dt);
```

Pasar los parametros a un DataTable

```
 var dtParametro = new DataTable();
                dtParametro.Columns.Add("parametro1", typeof(string));
                dtParametro.Columns.Add("parametro2", typeof(string));
                dtParametro.Columns.Add("parametro3", typeof(string));
                dtParametro.Columns.Add("parametro4", typeof(string));
            dtParametro.Rows.Add(drAdd);
                        // On all tables' columns
                    }


Despues con un For llenamos el DataTable con la informacion de la tabla DBF

  foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {

                        drAdd["TYPE"] = dr["parametro1"].ToString(); 
                        drAdd["EMPLOYEE"] = dr["parametro2"].ToString(); 
                        drAdd["CHECK"] = dr["parametro3"].ToString();
                        drAdd["ITEM"] = dr["parametro4"].ToString();
           
                        dtParametro.Rows.Add(drAdd);
           
                    }
```

Finalmente me conecto a la base de datos sql server y llamo al store procedure

```
string cadena1 = @"conexionabdd...";

                var cmda = new SqlCommand("Insertar_tbl_GNDITEM1", new SqlConnection(cadena));
                cmda.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmda.Parameters.Add("@param", SqlDbType.Structured).Value = dtParametro;

                cmda.Connection.Open(); // abrimos la conexion
                cmda.ExecuteNonQuery(); // lo ejecutamso
                cmda.Connection.Close(); // cerramos la conexion
```

Revisamos la base de datos y vemos que ya lo datos se encuentran en los mismos

PD: Adicional a esto deben crear la base de datos en el sql server, tambien crear un datatype para esa tabla y el store procedure aqui esta el video con el que me guie espero que sea de ayuda para alguien mas [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SL_iFbJhZQg&t=321s)